# Download files in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have loaded a website in my WebView which allows downloading mp3. However, you need to right click/long tap the download button and click "*save link as*" to download a mp3. If I just tap the download button, it starts streaming instead of downloading.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
    // download manager
            webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                        long contentLength) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                            mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            //download manager
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.beemp3s.org/");
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { // handle URLs in
                                                        // webview only
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

How do I force my code to download files instead of streaming? :)

Comment: Don't let the webview handle all urls. You are already extending `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)`

Comment: i want to download Everything within my webview only and using my own download manager

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if it will help but,try adding these lines.

```
private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("beemp3.org")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);

    }


    return true;

}
```